# Is there anyway to retrieve ALL tweets from twitter for the past x time (or how to stream all new real-time tweets)?

Tags: twitter

I'm trying to try to retrieve ALL tweets for an x time interval.

For example, I want to try to get all the tweets posted in the past 5 seconds (no specific word search in the query) - how would I be able to do this? I tried searching twitter documentation for a solution using the REST/Search/Streaming API but I've had no luck. I tried searching for an empty string as my query, but I get an invalid input as my response.

If anybody has any idea on how to do this it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks